# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in line 34

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, php5

Realizo un modulo donde se pueden filtrar los registros por diferentes campos No. de Control `id_Control`, Tipo de empresa `idctg_empresa` y por Turno `idctg_turno`. En mi BD esta diseñada para que en mi tabla `trabajador` tenga llaves foráneas de otras tablas esta compuesta por los siguientes datos:

```
id_Control
nombre
ap_paterno
ap_materno
NSS
CURP
RFC
fecha_nec
id_puesto     FK
id_area       FK
idctg_turno   FK
idctg_empresa FK
id_nomina     FK
```

Mi problema es el siguiente me muestra los datos correctamente que se encuentran en mi BD

```html
?php
 
 require_once ("../config/conexion.php");
?>

<?php
   
$action='ajax';
 if($action == 'ajax'){
         $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $sTable = "trabajador t";
    $sTable1 = "puesto P";
    $sTable2 = "area a";
    $sTable3 = "ctg_turno tu";
    $sTable4 = "empresa e";
    $sTable5 = "nomina n";
   $sWhere = "";
   $sWhere.="WHERE t.id_Control<=1000";
  if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
  {
  $sWhere.= " and tu.descripcion  like '$q' or e.descripcion_empresa  like '$q' or  t.t.id_Control like '$q' or  a.descripcion_area like '$q'   ";
   
  }
  
  //$sWhere.=" order by id_Control asc";
  include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
  //pagination variables
  $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
  $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
  $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
  $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
  //Count the total number of row in your table*/
  $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
  $numrows = $row['numrows'];
  $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
  $reload = './buscar.php';
  //main query to fetch the data
  $sql="SELECT t.id_Control, t.nombre, t.ap_paterno, t.ap_materno, t.NSS, t.CURP, t.RFC, t.fecha_nac, p.descripcion_puesto, a.descripcion_area, tu.descripcion, e.descripcion_empresa, n.descripcion_nomina 
  FROM $sTable
  INNER JOIN  $sTable1 ON t.id_puesto = p.id_puesto
  INNER JOIN $sTable2 ON t.id_area = a.id_area 
  INNER JOIN $sTable3  ON t.idctg_turno = tu.idctg_turno 
  INNER JOIN $sTable4 ON t.idctg_empresa = e.idctg_empresa 
  INNER JOIN $sTable5 ON t.id_nomina = n.id_nomina $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";

  //$sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  //loop through fetched data
  if ($numrows>0){
   echo mysqli_error($con);
   ?>
   <div class="table-responsive ">
     <table class="table table-hover" style="border-color: #337ab7;">
    <tr style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #337ab7;">
     <th>No. Control</th>
     <th>Nombre</th>
     <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
     <th>Apellido Materno</th>
     <th>NSS</th>
     <th>CURP</th>
     <th>RFC</th>
     <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
     <th>Puesto</th>
     <th>Area</th>
     <th>Turno</th>
     <th>Empresa</th>
     <th>Nomina</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $id_Control=$row['id_Control'];
      $nombre=$row['nombre'];
      $ap_paterno=$row['ap_paterno'];
      $ap_materno=$row['ap_materno'];
      $NSS=$row['NSS'];
      $CURP=$row['CURP'];
      $RFC=$row['RFC'];
      $fecha_nac=$row['fecha_nac'];
      $id_puesto=$row['descripcion_puesto'];
      $id_area=$row['descripcion_area'];
      $idctg_turno=$row['descripcion'];
      $idctg_empresa=$row['descripcion_empresa'];
      $id_nomina=$row['descripcion_nomina'];
  
     ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($id_Control); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($nombre);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($ap_paterno);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($ap_materno);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($NSS);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($CURP);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($RFC);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($fecha_nac);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($id_puesto);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($id_area);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($idctg_turno);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($idctg_empresa); ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($id_nomina); ?></td> 
           
     </tr>
     <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td colspan=7><span class="pull-right"><?
      echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
     ?></span></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <?php
  }
 }
?>
```

sin hacer el `inner JOIN` me busca los registros por los parametros que yo le pido, pero al hacer el Inner Join ya me muestra las descripciones de las tablas pero me marca el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vistas\ajax\buscar_usuario.php on
>   line 34

Comment: La función mysqli_query devuelve False cuando ocurre un error como parece ser el caso. Por eso luego la variable $count_query tiene ese valor y al hacer un fetch de un booleano arroja ese error. Yo comprobaría que la cadena de la consulta sql se está formando correctamente. Puede que tenga algún error de sintaxis.

Comment: Aplica la 1ª regla que te evitará tener que romperte la cabeza buscando dónde está el error: **depura la variable que estás pasando como consulta SQL y que está provocando el fallo en la línea 34**. O sea, imprime esa variable, y revísala, es muy probable que tenga algún error de sintaxis: un nombre de tabla o columna mal escrito, una comilla de más o de menos, etc, etc, etc. **1ª regla: depurar las variables.**

Comment: el problema es que al hacer el inner join, el valor del campo comparativo debe estar registrado en ambas tablas, si por ejemplo tienes el código de empresa en la tabla 1, pero no en la tabla 2 y es el campo de comparación, te dará ese error porque no arrojara resultados

Comment: @CarlosQuintero Gracias por responder, pero en mis dos tablas tengo las los id correspondientes solo lo que no tengo son las descripciones ya que las toma de la tabla foranea.